# Customize user location pin with MapBox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm using

> mapView.tintColor = UIColor.white

to change the user location pin's color. How can I replace it by an image?

Comment: Are you using google maps?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using google maps sdk, you can set the marker image using :

```
marker.icon = UIImage(name: "imageName")
```

Here marker is a `GMSMarker` type object.

Comment: what about "MapBox" in title?

Comment: Are you talking about info window?